# APS.NET MVC - Split de dados da BD

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Necessito de fazer uma função em VB a qual permita listar numa DropDown os dados de um campo na base de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho de listar os dados do campo 'EixoX' (da figura acima) na DropDown. A dúvida está no seguinte:
Eu preciso de listar  os dados da BD a partir de um determinado ID, por exemplo ID=1, onde terei que fazer o split por ',' do que está no Campo 'EixoX'.

Até agora consegui fazer o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver ele lista todas as linhas do campo 'EixoX'.

Como posso fazer que ele liste apenas o campo a partir de um determinado ID, tendo que tenho de fazer o split do seu conteúdo e apresentar cada um individualmente? 
Por exemplo, para o ID=1 teria que apresentar o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Faz o `select` para recuperar por id, e faz o split do retorna da coluna EixoX assim por exemplo:

```
 eixoX = "a1, a2, a3"
 Dim eixoSValores As String() = eixoX.Split(New Char() {","c})
```

Comment: Obrigado! Vou ver se consigo resolver usando essa estratégia :)